# Program not asking expected number of values

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
  int n,i;
  FILE *fptr;
  fptr=fopen("f3.txt","w");
  if(fptr==NULL)
  {
    printf("Error!");
    exit(1);
  }
  printf("Enter n: ");
  for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
  {
    scanf("%d \n",&n);
    fprintf(fptr,"%d ",n);
  }
  fclose(fptr);
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** **In the above program, I am entering 3 values, but why this is asking for 4 values? Although its writing only three times but its asking for the values 4 times. Can u tell d reason? And what to do to make it to take exact number of values which I am typing.?** thanks in advance..

**So this is known that it was due to space next to %d in loop. Can someone explain Carriage Return in a little detail, I searched but could not understand exactly what that is.**

Comment: `for(i=0;i<=2;i++)` = { i | 0, 1, 2 }

Comment: the loop is for 3 times. how can you enter 4 values?

Comment: Carriage return means to press the ENTER/RETURN key (that big key located under the backspace key in most keyboards)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not entering 4 values, but 3. The `for` statement runs through 0, 1 and 2. If it seems it's asking you for 4 values is because of the format string you have used in `scanf()`. Just use `"%d"`, without the trailing space and the `\n`.

Also, may I suggest that you repeat the `printf ("Enter n: ");` just before the `scanf()` and not only at the beginning of your program? That way, you'll quickly realize when the program is asking you for data, or when `scanf()` has just been stucked waiting for some trailing data, for example, a carriage return, to accept previous data.

If you change the `printf` as I tell you and don't change the format string in `scanf()`, you will realize that your program asks for the first number, then asks for a carriage return (you thought here it's asking you for a number, and enter one, your "second" number), then asks for the second number (the third number to you, but this `scanf()` will accept the second one you previously entered), and then for the third number (the fourth to you, but this `scanf()` will accept the previous third number entered). That's 4 inputs by the user, and that is what have confused you.

To try to explain what is happening with your scanf() as you originally have it, I've written a program based upon yours, but with a few additions:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int n,i,c;

  for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
  {
    printf ("  scanf #%d (%%d) \n", i+1);
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf ("  Read: %d\n",n);
    c = getchar();
    printf ("  Last character in input buffer: %.2X\n", c);
    printf ("  scanf #%d (space and \\n) \n", i+1);
    scanf(" \n"); /* or \t or just the space, or just \n */
    c = getchar();
    printf ("  Last character in input buffer: %.2X\n", c);
    ungetc (c, stdin);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Everytime the program stills, the user enters a number: 1,2,3,4,... The sequence `getchar/ungetch` peeks at the input buffer to see what is the first thing the next `scanf()` will find. I've also splitted your `scanf()` into two calls: the first one using `%d` and the second one using the rest of your format string (space and/or `\n`). Note that \n is treated as a space. In fact, both are part of the so called **blank characters** so anyone of them behaves the same, and more than one blank behaves like there is only one blank)

This is what happens (numbers at the left are the numbers I enter from the keyboard):

```
  scanf #1 (%d)
1
  Read: 1
  Last character in input buffer: 0A
  scanf #1 (space and \n)
2
  Last character in input buffer: 32
  scanf #2 (%d)
  Read: 2
  Last character in input buffer: 0A
  scanf #2 (space and \n)
3
  Last character in input buffer: 33
  scanf #3 (%d)
  Read: 3
  Last character in input buffer: 0A
  scanf #3 (space and \n)
4
  Last character in input buffer: 34
  END OF PROGRAM
```

Compare this output with this one:

```
  scanf #1 (%d)
1 2 3 4  <-- I enter 4 numbers at the first prompt, instead of one at a time
  Read: 1
  Last character in input buffer: 20
  scanf #1 (space and \n)
  Last character in input buffer: 32
  scanf #2 (%d)
  Read: 2
  Last character in input buffer: 20
  scanf #2 (space and \n)
  Last character in input buffer: 33
  scanf #3 (%d)
  Read: 3
  Last character in input buffer: 20
  scanf #3 (space and \n)
  Last character in input buffer: 34
  END OF PROGRAM
```

Comment: No I want to write 3 values only, but the thing is, even after scanf statement is in the same loop, its asking for values 4 times. That means I can give 4 values, although this will write 3 values only. Why is this asking for 4 values, I want to change that to 3..

Comment: Then leave the for as it was. I've already explaned to you why it is asking for 4 values even while you run the loop 3 times.

Comment: Yes, removing that space worked, but can you tell me what is the reason for such a behavior here.?

Comment: Thanx a tonn for the answer, but please tell me how that space was causing it to ask 4 times.?

Comment: It's actually any blank character: space, \n, \t... My answer doesn't say anything that the \n is causing the failure. Besides: if you leave the \n and take off the space, the program will stil seem to ask for 4 values. I've said that in a comment, so, why the downvote? I'll update that comment.

Comment: Then I will revoke the downvote. Whitespace in a scanf means to eat anything on the stdin buffer. Thus, it eats the first \n after entering the number.

Comment: +1 for your effort mate, its the Space only, but your explanation really helped me a lot. I did not expect downvotes on the ques thoughth. Although its very easy to answer, but seriously downvoting this was not such a good idea..

Comment: kindly update your answer to show the respective concept. I can't remove my downvote till then.

Comment: @akshat:: Downvoting is done to let the user know that he/she has written or implying something wrong. Its for the betterment of the answer. And it will help a lot readers of this question.

Answer (score 1):

change your for loop into, then you can enter 4 values

```
for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
{
 scanf("%d \n",&n);
 fprintf(fptr,"%d ",n);
}
```

Comment: No I want to write 3 values only, but the thing is, even after scanf statement is in the same loop, its asking for values 4 times. That means I can give 4 values, although this will write 3 values only. Why is this asking for 4 values, I want to change that to 3..

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    main()
    {
      int n,i;
      FILE *fptr;
      fptr=fopen("f3.txt","w");
      if(fptr==NULL)
      {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(1);
      }
      printf("Enter n: ");
      for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
      {
        scanf("%d \n",&n);
        fprintf(fptr,"%d ",n);
      }
      fclose(fptr);
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: No I want to write 3 values only, but the thing is, even after scanf statement is in the same loop, its asking for values 4 times. That means I can give 4 values, although this will write 3 values only. Why is this asking for 4 values, I want to change that to 3..

Answer (score 0):

Your code takes only 3 values, not 4.

> for(i=0;i<=2;i++)

the above loop runs for 0, 1 and 2, that is 3 times.

Comment: No I want to write 3 values only, but the thing is, even after scanf statement is in the same loop, its asking for values 4 times. That means I can give 4 values, although this will write 3 values only. Why is this asking for 4 values, I want to change that to 3..

Answer (score 0):

The `for(i=0;i<=2;i++)` loops for 3 times only , change it to `for(i=0;i<4;i++)` and the answer to your edits:: change `scanf("%d \n",&n);` to `scanf("%d",&n);` (spot the difference in space after `%d`).

Comment: No I want to write 3 values only, but the thing is, even after scanf statement is in the same loop, its asking for values 4 times. That means I can give 4 values, although this will write 3 values only. Why is this asking for 4 values, I want to change that to 3..

Comment: @Akshat:: White space (such as blanks, tabs, or newlines) in the format string match any amount of white space, including none, in the input.

Comment: @Akshat: Why exactly have you used a "Space" and a "\n" character in your "scanf" ?